# how can i upload file directly from url to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can I upload file from url directly without download it and upload it to server ??

like if i have a link

```
http://whatever/test.pdf
```

put it into textbox and upload it !!

Comment: the phrase "download file using c#" returns dozens of articles. Are you sure you tried to google using the similar terms?

Comment: i did not know if it is the same like downloading file ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `System.Net.WebClient`:

```
var url = textBox1.Text;

var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(url, "c:\\path-to-save-file-on-server\\test.pdf");
```

Comment: is this code to download it from server ??1

Comment: This code gets a web location from the textBox1 (something like http://whatever/test.pdf).  It gets the file from that location and saves it to the c:\ drive on your web server.

Comment: i want to upload a file i have to options first one to upload file from client to server using fileupload control and the second one is to give a link and then upload it !!

Comment: Yeah, you can use file upload if a user has a file already.  If the user has a url and wants to copy it from the web straight to your web server without downloading/uploading, you could use something like the code example above.

Comment: okay thanks i'll try it
another thing if i wont to rename can it must be a method also like fileupload control ??

Comment: If you want to rename it, you can save it under whatever file name you want.  Like `client.DownloadFile(url, "c:\\somewhere\\renamed.pdf");`

Comment: can i use it in .net framework 3.5 ??!

Comment: Yes, you can: [documentation for .net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)